# MySQL compare rows without an Id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I am trying to query all the records where the MACD is positive and from that record the previous one has a negative MACD on my MySQL server. Here is a sample of my table:

```
+---------------------+------+
|    DateTimeGMT0     | MACD |
+---------------------+------+
| 2021-04-26 01:30:00 | 12   |
| 2021-04-25 03:45:00 | 1    |
| 2021-04-22 10:56:00 | -5   |
| 2021-04-22 02:01:00 | -20  |
+---------------------+------+
```

Now there is one important rule:

> You can't use Id columns in the query, because those are not in the
> correct order

I already found this post: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-compare-two-rows-from-same-table/

But unfortunately he uses the Id columns. I have actually no idea how to query the previous row!?

In my case, the wanted result is:

```
+---------------------+------+
| 2021-04-25 03:45:00 | 1    |
+---------------------+------+
```

But when there are more, I want them all, so not just one!

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`;

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(macd) over (order by DateTimeGMT0) as prev_macd
      from t
     ) t
where mac > 0 and prev_macd < 0;
```